# how to extract the pattern out of each sentence with [xxx][xxxx] pattern in the end

Tags: terminal, regular-expression, macintosh

I have a file containing such sentences:

```
..........[xxxx][xxxx]
..........[xxxx][xxxx]
..........[xxxx][xxxx]
```

with two [][] in the end of each sentence, how can I extract the [][] and corresponding content inside the [][] out into a new file, like this:

```
[xxxx][xxxx]
[xxxx][xxxx]
[xxxx][xxxx]
```

I have tried terminal regular expression, but it did not work out.
Thanks,

Comment: it is one sentence per line, so [][] pair appear in the end of each line. the output also needs to be each pair [][] per line.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with GNU `grep` (or any other `grep` that supports the `-o` option):

```
grep -o '\[[^]]*\]\[[^]]*\]$' file > new_file
```

Output:

```
[xxxx][xxxx]
[xxxx][xxxx]
[xxxx][xxxx]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `grep` supports `-o`, and  there are no other `[` on the line, so you want everything after the first `[`:

```
$ grep -oP '[^]]*\K\[.*' file 
[xxxx][xxxx]
[xxxx][xxxx]
[xxxx][xxxx]
```

If you can have other `[` which you don't want, try:

```
$ grep -oP '.*\K\[.+?\]\[.*' file 
[xxxx][xxxx]
[xxxx][xxxx]
[xxxx][xxxx]
```

And if you don't have a `grep` that supports `-o` (I believe [the macOS one does](https://ss64.com/osx/grep.html)), you can use:

```
$ sed -E 's/.*(\[.+?\]\[.*)/\1/' file 
[xxxx][xxxx]
[xxxx][xxxx]
[xxxx][xxxx]
```

Answer (score 1):

POSIX sed:

```
sed 's/.*\(\[[^]]*\]\[[^]]*\]\)$/\1/' file
```

- `\[[^]]*\]` matches `[`, any number of non-`]`, another `]`.
- `\(\[[^]]*\]\[[^]]*\]\)$` matches two of them, anchored at the end of line, which are captured by `\(\)` in the first and only capture group.
- `\1` only the captured group is kept in the output.